# Qt - setting up an interface

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, installation

We can for example set up a user interface in `Qt` as follows:

```
Ui::Dialog ui;
ui.setupUi(dialog);
```

Here, I will setup the UI of `dialog` to `ui`.

But, if I write the following:

```
setupUi(this)
```

What does that mean? Especially that I'm not assigining a specific user interface (i.e; ui). How will I setup an interface that way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Namespace UI is controlled by the UIC (ui compiler). basically, a UI file is adescription of the internal of a UI. To instanciate it, you need to tell it which widget it's supposed to populate. In your case, you explicitely tell it to fill the "dialog" widget.

If you're inside a class derivating from qwidget, then of course, you can use

```
ui.setupUi(this)
```

I'm not sure I perfectly understood your question, so feel free to provide details and I'll complete my answer.

Comment: Hehe, are you answering your own question? :)

Comment: No, I just edited the inital post from user588855 to add tags, I was just not sure to understand the question "What does that mean? Especially that I'm not assigining a specific interface (i.e; ui). How will I setup an interface that way?"

Comment: Ah, right missed that. Yes, the question could be more verbose, I agree. Some context is missing...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The class such code is in is `gotocelldialog.cpp`. And, `setupUi(this)` is written **without** `ui.`. In this case, how will that work out? And, why did you assume that the class is deriving from `QWidget`? As the header file `.h` of this `.cpp` file derives as follows `class GoToCellDialog: public QDialog, public Ui::GoToCellDialog`. So, I didn't notice where `QWidget` derivation is if you can clarify this point. Thanks

Comment: Would be interesting to have more code then :-) Your gotoCellDialog is a QDialog (thus a QWidget) and a UI generated class (which is not the most common way of doing it). running setupUi(this) will fill the QDialog with the Ui::gotCellDialog you're derivating from. The first example with instanciate a new UI and use it to fill a provided dialog (hope this helps). Note that usually, you don't derivate from UI classes, you aggregate them in something else.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between passing "dialog" and "this" is that when you pass "dialog", the UI elements that you created in Qt Designer will be put on "dialog" widget as you specify it to be put on, while when you pass "this", the UI elements will be put on this widget ( the widget from the method of which you're calling setupUi() )